# Vimdiff copy above/below

Tags: vim, diff, merge

`do` and `dp`  are kinda limited to take one or another version of the conflict, in many cases it's just java `import`s when you need both changes, is there any way to make a map that copies the other side's conflict above/below the current line?

I can't find any plugin that does that...

Comment: I'm curious, too. For now I'm doing "dd ^w^w p dp".